# Dynamic ui-router > uiSref directive doesn't generate href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I spend a lot time, but can't find the solution for dynamic ui-router, exactly for generating "href" according to "ui-sref"
this solution has the same problem, you can see it here [plunker preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/OId0A6?p=preview)

I tried write this:

```js
require(['config'], function() {
  require([
    'angular',
    './app',
    './controllers/ListCtrl',
    './controllers/TwoViewsCtrl'
  ], function (angular, app) {
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;
      $urlRouterProviderRef = $urlRouterProvider;
    }]);

    app.run(['$http', '$urlRouter', '$state',
      function ($http, $urlRouter, $state) {

        $http.get('/json/routes.json').success(function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];

            var getExistingState = $state.get(obj.state);
            if(getExistingState !== null)
              return;

            $stateProviderRef.state(obj.state, obj);
          };

            $urlRouter.sync();
            $urlRouter.listen();
        });

    }]);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['uiRouts']);
    });

  });
});
```

or second solution:

```js
require(['config'], function() {
  require([
    'angular',
    './app',
    './controllers/ListCtrl',
    './controllers/TwoViewsCtrl'
  ], function (angular, app) {
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
      var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

        $http.get('/json/routes.json').success(function(data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
                $stateProvider.state(obj.state, obj);
          };
        });

    }]);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['uiRouts']);
    });

  });
});
```

but if I use this solution not inside the success callback function, just put .JSON inside app.config, all works fine.